# My 2-year-old-son is eating small black stones. How to stop this habit?

Tags: toddler, food, habits

My 2-year-old son is eating small black stones when he is playing outside. We were really shocked he considered those as "chips", and he tries to bite the stones and swallows them very often. Now we are not allowing him to play outside because we were really scared whether it will hurt his stomach.

Could any one please let us know how to stop this habit? How can we make him understand a "stone" is different from what he is thinking, and he's not allowed to eat it?

Comment: Forget more stones, first take him to the doctor for the existing stones that he has eaten. No?

Comment: @Hanky Panky. Yes we did. Now he is alright. but our worries is how to stop this behavior in future.

Comment: Maybe some answer(s) to my question here may help: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/34242/toddler-putting-small-stones-in-her-mouth-thinking-its-funny

Answer (score 0):

My uncle had a similar problem with his kids eating dried up leaves outside in the park. I don't remember the story fully, but funny story was that he brought some home and put hot sauce on it and let him eat a little and now he associates it as spicy leaves. This was back in Thailand awhile back.